# Base class '<baseclassname1>' specified for class '<partialclassname>' cannot be different

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, base-class, partial-classes

> "Base class `<baseclassname1>` specified for class
>   '' cannot be different from the base class
>   '' of one of its other partial types"

The problem is that I only declared the class in one place, the actual class file, and only **declared** it once, **non partially**. 
All my other classes that inherit from **"DialogBase"** work fine, but one file with the most code just stopped working.

What else could be the problem? Could it be declared partial somewhere else?

```
Class CostDialog inherits DialogBase(This works fine)

Class Blend inherits DialogBase(This errors)
```

`Blend` is only written as `Public Class Blend` in the `Blend.vb` file ONCE
This error makes no sense

Comment: Check if there are any hidden designer-generated files in the solution.

Comment: Google says .. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d17t7cd.aspx

Comment: David, I explain in the question that there IS NO partial declaration on any of these classes. That MSDN solution is inapplicable

Answer (score 1):

You may have multiple code behind files with the same class name. I was converting a web site to a web application and found that there were two instances of Home. So Project/abc/home.aspx /aspx.vb and Project/def/home.aspx/ /aspx.vb will cause a conflict if both home.aspx.vb files have the same class name.

**My fix** was to leave all the file names untouched but modify the class name to abc_home and def_home in their respective code behind file and then change the Inherits property at the top of their .aspx pages.

Highly doubt this is still an issue for you, but maybe for someone else.